# Debugging/Navigating JS Code in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, navigation, requirejs

Is there anyway to enable **f12** or **find all references** across **Javascript** files in **Visual Studio**? I'm using **requireJS** to register the js files in my SPA. I'm using **BackboneJS** as well.

Any tips for flipping through relavent code in Visual Studio like I can with C#/.net code? I've searched around online and investigated myself but couldn't find anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

to enable F12 navigation to JS function source defined in another .js file you need to add the following line to the top of the current .js file where you reference the external function:

```
/// <reference path="../Path/To/The/Referenced/file.js" />
```

The ../ part is optional, just build the correct path yourself. After the above chunk is added Visual Studio successfully finds the definition of the external js function upon F12 hit on its reference. At least it works for me with VS2013 Premium.