# How to navigate in Javascript code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I wonder how to navigate in Javascript code in VS code.

To figure out the behavior, I made this little project :

- js
- js/index.js
- js/foo.js

index.js

```
var person = {}

person.name = "azeaze"

person.sayHello = function() {
  console.log("Hi! My name is ", this.name)
}
```

foo.js

```
console.log('In foo module')

person.sayHello()
```

jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "include": [
        "js/*"
    ]
}
```

What I need is to navigate, from the foo.js file when I click on person.sayHello. I tried Cmd-click or F12 but VS Code replies "No definition found for sayHello". Why VS code can't?

May be the use of module is required? If so, is there a way to handle legacy code (pure ES5 code) who don't provide it? And what the purpose of "include" in jsconfig.json, if the IDE only need to follow the require?

Edit : 
I tried to follow this answer [Debugging/Navigating JS Code in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559881/debugging-navigating-js-code-in-visual-studio), that is to say add to foo.js :

```
/// <reference path="../Path/To/The/Referenced/index.js" />
```

But F12 navigation still doesn't work.

(I'm on Mac OS 10.12 and VS Code 1.13)

Comment: Try `Ctrl+click`, it usually works in VS code for me

Comment: I tried that and F12 navigation but VS Code doesn't understand it.

Comment: If your cursor is on the sayHello() part of person.sayHello() and you push CTRL/CMD key does nothing happen?  Same with f12?  They both work for me.

Comment: No it doesn't work for me. Cmd-click doesn't do anything and F12 displays "No definition found for sayHello"...
Interesting fact, if a make a constructor in index.js (ex: var Personne = function() {}), I can use it in foo.js with autocompletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copy/paste the answer from the official github's VS Code : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28495#event-1119847030.

---

The TypeScript service that powers our JS and TS language currently cannot recognize properties added to an object after it is created.

The best workaround is to define all the properties in the object literal:

```
var person = {
   name: "azeaze",
   sayHello: function() {
     console.log("Hi! My name is ", this.name)
  }
}
```

or to add an explicit type using jsdocs:

```
/**
 * @type {{ name: string, sayHello: () => void}}
 */
// @ts-ignore
var person = {}

person.name = "azeaze"

person.sayHello = function() {
  console.log("Hi! My name is ", this.name)
}
```